# JS: Replace for loop with filter, map or foreach

Tags: javascript

I have such method:

```
  function sort(arr) {
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      if (arr[i].title !== 'Test') {
        arr[i] = {
          ...arr[i],
          data: sortByType(arr[i].data),
          full: sortByType(arr[i].full)
        };
      }
    }

    return arr;
  }
```

Can it be simplified to use filter or foreach?

Comment: Please show inputs and expected outputs so that answerers can ensure their functions work as expected. Please also show what you've tried so far, and any research you've done.

Answer (score 2):

I have done it with map:

I havent tested it, but should work like you original code

```
function sort(arr) {
   return arr.map(el => {
      if(el.title === "Test") return el;
      return { ...el, data: sortByType(el.data), full: sortByType(el.full) }
   })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that your loop is the simplest right now.

Image you want to switch it to using a `map`, your code will become:

```js
function sort(arr) {
    return arr.map(elem => {
      // you now need to handle this case too
      if (elem.title === "Test") 
        return elem;

      return { 
        ...elem, 
        data: sortByType(elem.data), 
        full: sortByType(elem.full) 
      }
    });
}
```

Which is essentially more code, and I don't think you gain anything from it imho.

A filter won't work in your case though.

Answer (score 0):

this should help

```js
function sort(arr) {
    return arr.map((item) =>{
        if(item.title != "Test") {
            item = {
                ...item, 
                data: sortByType(item.data),
                full: sortByType(item.full)
            }
        }
        return item;
    })
}
```